# FlutterErrorDetail How to get class name of error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using this code to catch errors in my flutter application and it works perfectly but I want to know the error happen in which page or class. !

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ErrorWidget-class.html

```
   ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) {
           return CustomError(errorDetails: errorDetails);
         };



class CustomError extends StatefulWidget {
  final FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails;
  final Widget? page;

  CustomError({
    Key? key,
    required this.errorDetails,
    this.page,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomError> createState() => _CustomErrorState();
}

class _CustomErrorState extends State<CustomError> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          child: Text(
            "Something is not right here...",
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        ),
        color: Colors.red,
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get where the error happened you need to get the [StackTrace](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/StackTrace-class.html), it should be stored inside [FlutterErrorDetails.stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/FlutterErrorDetails/stack.html). You can display it using `toString()`.

```
child: Text(
    "Something is not right here.\nStack trace: ${widget.errorDetails.stack?.toString() ?? '(no stack trace stored in error)'}",
    style: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
),
```